# Writing multiple dataframes to new workbook

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to loop through a folder to pick up some data sets then append them into one workbook. I keep getting an error when trying to use pd.ExcelWriter to achieve the intention,

Trying to use both of these methods below comes up with the error Abstract class 'ExcelWriter' with abstract methods instantiated

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(home, engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(home, engine='openpyxl', mode='a')
```